# Interrupt Runnable that takes hours

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, threadpoolexecutor

I have a ThreadPoolExecutor:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor service = new ThreadPoolExecutor(N_THREADS, N_THREADS, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, blockingQueue, rejectedExecutionHandler);
```

The service executes threads implementing the Runnable interface. Each thread processes a file on disk. I found that after several hours, two threads (or cores depending on what htop shows in Linux) were running and had been running for 13 hours. What's even worse is that the remaining cores showed no activity as if they were waiting for the two threads to complete.

Questions:
1 - I have read a lot on how this problem may be resolved but nothing conclusive. As far as I can work out, you CANNOT stop a Runnable using the ThreadPoolExecutor because it is an independent thread that just runs. Using the Future framework:

```
Future<?> f = f.get(submittedtask,XX)
```

allows you to set a timeout and fetch the future result, but get blocks all the threads effectively making the implementation serial. Is it possible to interrupt a Runnable after a given time using the threadpoolexecutor, get the thread back to the pool so it can pickup a new task and carry on.

2 - My big concern is why, using htop, I see two threads/cores running and no other core/thread are running despite many tasks are still waiting to execute (i.e. there are many files left to process). Any insight?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel%28boolean%29. Regarding the number of busy cores: what's the value of N_THREADS? How many cores do you have?

Comment: Attach a debugger to the running JVM. In order to do this, you have to have started the JVM with the right debugging options.

Comment: N_Threads is 24, so 12 cores (Intel Xeon E5 something)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a second scheduled thread pool to which you would submit cancellation tasks for each of the returned `Future`s. Each of these tasks after a given timeout would check if it's associated `Future` is done and if not, cancel it. Cancellation would trigger thread interruption, so you might need to support it in your tasks by checking the interrupted flag: `Thread.interrupted()`.

The size of this second thread pool could be minimal, i.e. 1 as this job takes minimum of CPU time.

Code example:

```
ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

...

while(...){
    final Future<?> f = pool.submit(...);

    service.schedule(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(!f.isDone()){
                f.cancel(true);
            }
        }
    }, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}

service.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
service.shutdown();
```

Comment: Interesting idea. So jobs are submitted to the ThreadedExecutorPool named pool, and the other service cancel it if it takes too long. My question is how generalizable this is to machines with many cores and threads. To me it seems that the schedule has to wait for a particular job to finish for every submit that is made. Doesnt that create a bottle neck?

Comment: Sorry, I missed your question. The scheduled jobs are put into a queue and are retrieved when their time comes. The bottleneck for the `ScheduledExecutorService` is the insertion/deletion which is `O(log n)` + lock time. I don't think this will create any trouble in most situations, though the best thing might be to measure it for your case.

Comment: Yea that was my concern but if insertion deletion is that fast then, as you say, I also doubt it will cause problems. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can tell a thread that you **wish** to [`interrupt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html):

> An interrupt is an **indication** to a thread that it should stop what it is doing and do something else.

You can interrupt your thread with [`Future.cancel(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel%28boolean%29). It's in your responsibility to implement the Runnable in a manner that it obeys that wish by checking its [`Thread.interrupted()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted%28%29) state.

Answer (score 0):

In order to see details about process thread run:

```
ps -eLf | grep <PROCESS_PID>
```

Since htop shows you the running processes list, where each process has at least one thread.